# Exporting SVG image to points using bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I have this script that is supposed to export .svg image in an array like

```
    0:( 0.0,0.0 ),
    1:( 6.53459,1.66722 ),
    2:( 7.59595,-1.6522 ),
    3:( 4.22184,-3.83134 ),
    4:( -3.58776,-4.87022 ),
    5:( -7.57144,-4.6225 ),
    6:( -5.11039,-7.0874 ),
    7:( -8.74994,-15.13315 ),
    ...
```

But it is not working.. any ideas why? I researched everything I could and I had no luck.

Here is a script. It is taken from Robert Bennett gihub.

```
#!/bin/bash

 Author Robert Bennett

for file in $@
do
  array=grep "\bd=" $file | sed -r "s/(-)?[0-9]+(\.)?(-)?([0-9]*)?,(-)?[0-9]+(\.)?(-)?([0-9]*)?/{ & },\n/g" | grep -o "{.*},"
  echo "$array"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "array" variable is not well initialized. To capture the output of the commands you are executing, they should be sourrounded by $()

With this change, the script works for me:

```
array=$(grep "\bd=" $file | sed -r "s/(-)?[0-9]+(\.)?(-)?([0-9]*)?,(-)?[0-9]+(\.)?(-)?([0-9]*)?/{ & },\n/g" | grep -o "{.*},")
```